# Value iteration example maybe wrong?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In this [link](https://artint.info/html/ArtInt_227.html), the agent moves stochastically: 70% in the direction decided and 10% in any of the other 3 directions. If it goes out of the map, it incurs a -1 payoff and stays in the same cell.

Now the reason, I think something is wrong is that if you look at the upper left corner, in V1, we can either choose right or down, say we choose down (say the discount factor is 0.9):

V1(S(0, 0)) = 0.7 * (0 + 0.9 * 0) + 0.1 * (0 + 0.9 * 0) + 0.1 * (-1 + 0.9 * 0) + 0.1 * (-1 + 0.9 * 0).

On the right-hand side, the order of the terms: going down, going right, going left, going up.
Notice that although the agent chooses to go down, the other terms represent the stochasticity of the output. Does that make any sense?

The other question, how does V1(S(1, 1)) 9.8? Shouldn't it be a combination of the cells nearby or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/fqzpqo/a_little_problem_with_value_iteration/), The 3x3 grid that is shown is just a smaller part of the larger grid displayed in [example 9.26](https://artint.info/html/ArtInt_224.html#gridworld-ex): So the top left corner in the 3x3 grid is actually not surrounded by walls. Example 9.26 also explains what happens when the agent reaches the +10 tile.